# Unknown file - wp-config-db.cnf.php - any ideas?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Noticed a file in the root of my wordpress install yesterday.

It was called wp-config-db.cnf.php and inside it had the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
#<?php /*
[mysqldump]
user={username}
password={password}
#*/?>
```

Any ideas where this came from or what is it doing?

Is it a legitimate file or is it something to worry about?

Thanks

Comment: *Suspicious*. I would check your FTP/Access logs. That is not a common WP file. I would advise renaming or moving the file the file from your root.

Comment: I have deleted it already, and closed down FTP/SSH to only my IP address. Also found another person with the same problem (but only 1 so far). Could there be a legitimate reason for it? Would it allow anyone to view my database login from a browser?

Comment: It's presence suggest you may be vulnerable elsewhere. Check your logs. If you have an older version of WP, upgrade to the latest version. Upgrade your themes and plugins too if they need it. You're not out of the woods yet since you don't know how it got there.

Comment: yeah, that is my main worry - how it got there! Site was getting hammered yesterday both SSH and front end. Can't find any successful login attempts but I am not exactly sure where to look - which logs do I need to check? Wordpress, themes and plugins are all up to date.

Comment: You will want to forensically review your Access Logs, FTP Logs, and if you have logging for SSH. In the access logs you're looking for unusually high activity on specific files. Then review for unusual POST entries or GET queries. You can also review the IPs from FTP/SSH logs and cross reference to Access logs. Look for IPs that are scanning and attempting penetration. Can also use Scrawler to check your site.

Comment: what would be the location of these logs on CentOS6/Apache? I have FTP turned off. What is Scrawler?

Comment: We're way off topic. You will have to discuss that with your provider or your server admin. This is not the place for this.

Comment: seems like it was vaultpress - see my comment below

Answer (score 0):

Crisis over. I just spoke to VaultPress (a plugin I installed recently) and they said this:

> Could your plugin have made a file in the root of my wordpress install
>   called wp-config-db.cnf.php ?
>
> > Yes -- we use this file to pass MySQL credentials to your MySQL process during restores. If you're concerned about it, you can delete it, and we'll regenerate one when we attempt a restore.
> >
> > Best,
> >     Chris
> >
> > Automattic | WordPress.com | VaultPress